# write correctly mysql head file

Tags: mysql

How can I write this:

```
IF DB_ID('DB_NAME') IS NOT NULL DROP DATABASE MORPG1;
GO
CREATE DATABASE DB_NAME;
GO
USE DB_NAME
GO
```

Comment: Hi, it would be helpfull if you describe in a few sentences what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

All operations except `USE` can be performed with

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE recreate_datebase (dbname VARCHAR(64))
BEGIN
IF EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA
            WHERE SCHEMA_NAME = dbname ) THEN
    SET @sql := CONCAT('DROP DATABASE ', dbname);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
SET @sql := CONCAT('CREATE DATABASE ', dbname);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
```

Making the database current one cannot be parametrized / executed dynamically.